# Parameterized builds not working with the Pipeline AWS Steps s3 upload plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a parameterized build while using the Pipeline AWS Steps (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+AWS+Plugin). It works well but not together with this plugin. It gives an error somewhere during the Jenkins build process.

```
def s3BucketAcl = 'xxxxxxRead'
def s3BucketName = 'blah-s3-bucket'

properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: '*/master', description: '', name: 'BRANCH', trim: false)])])

node {
   stage('Checkout code from Git') {
      // Checkout code from a GitHub repository
      echo "Pulling changes from the branch ${params.BRANCH}"
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: ${params.BRANCH}]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', url: 'git@github.com:organisation/repo.git']]])
   }

   stage('Change directory to blah and upload files to S3')
   {
        dir('blah') {
            withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'aws-key', usernameVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', passwordVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
                s3Upload acl: s3BucketAcl, bucket: s3BucketName, file: 'vis-network.min.css', path: 'vis-network.min.css'

            }
        }
   }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Pulling changes from the branch */master
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [archive, awaitDeploymentCompletion, awsIdentity, bat, build, catchError, cfInvalidate, cfnCreateChangeSet, cfnDelete, cfnDeleteStackSet, cfnDescribe, cfnExecuteChangeSet, cfnExports, cfnUpdate, cfnUpdateStackSet, cfnValidate, checkout, deleteDir, deployAPI, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, ec2ShareAmi, echo, ecrLogin, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, invokeLambda, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, listAWSAccounts, load, lock, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, s3Copy, s3Delete, s3Download, s3FindFiles, s3PresignURL, s3Upload, script, setAccountAlias, sh, sleep, snsPublish, stage, stash, step, timeout, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash, updateIdP, updateTrustPolicy, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withAWS, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, credentials, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, githubPush, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, remotingCLI, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, triggeredBy, unsecured, upstream, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor694.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:156)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:130)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:130)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:20)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor693.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:347)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I will be grateful for any help with this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of investigation and research, I have been able to narrow down on the problem.

I changed `${params.BRANCH}` to `"${params.BRANCH}"` in the script for performing the git checkout. This resolved the problem.

Thank you very much all.